# Some files have truncated filenames with mkisofs -J -R

Tags: filenames, mkisofs

I have installed mkisofs 3.02a09 (i686-pc-mingw32) on Windows 10.

I'm trying to create an ISO with `mkisofs` but some filenames are truncated :

```
PS C:\tools> mkisofs -J -R -o VDI-Michelin-Editions-Master-20230929.iso .\VDI-Michelin-Editions-Master-20230929
C:\ProgramData\scoop\apps\cdrtools\current\mkisofs.exe: Warning: Cannot write inode/link information with -no-cache-inodes.
Using DISAB000.TXT;1 for  .\Master-20230929/config/disable_IPv6.cmd.txt (disable_Autorun_All_users.ps1.txt)
Using DISAB000.REG;1 for  .\Master-20230929/config/disable_Autorun_All_users.reg (Disable_APIPA.reg)
Using VMWAR000.CMD;1 for  .\Master-20230929/OSOT/VMwareOSOptimizationTool-OPTIMIZE.cmd (VMwareOSOptimizationTool-FINALIZE.cmd)
Using 537_1000.EXE;1 for  .\Master-20230929/packages/driver_v8/537.13_grid_win10_win11_server2019_server2022_dch_64bit_international.exe (537.13_grid_win10_win11_server2019_server2022_dch_64bit_int.exe)
  0.72% done, estimate finish Fri Sep 29 12:24:55 2023
...
 99.84% done, estimate finish Fri Sep 29 12:24:10 2023
Total translation table size: 0
Total rockridge attributes bytes: 4570
Total directory bytes: 12880
Path table size(bytes): 100
701117 extents written (1369 MB)
```

EDIT0 : How come the path `.\Master-20230929/packages/driver_v8/537.13_grid_win10_win11_server2019_server2022_dch_64bit_international.exe` which contains less than 255 characters (max Rock Ridge length) is truncated to `.\Master-20230929/packages/driver_v8/537.13_grid_win10_win11_server2019_server2022_dch_64bit_int.exe`

Comment: Also, is not mkisofs deprecated or am I missing something? Nowadays we use genisoimage

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'd be glad to use it if you know a portable version of genisoimage for Windows.

Comment: In the past I've used to use Microsoft's own `cdimage.exe`, although it is even older... but, the formats haven't really changed much since 2000, have they? If the tool worked back then, it should still work today.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Interesting, where can I get for Windows 10 ?

Comment: The general question was answered in September (or rather responded to, because it was not even a question back then). Your "EDIT0" introduces a specific question, it smells like a [chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310). I'm not voting down, but "going chameleon" is never a good idea on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you enable the Joliet and Rock Ridge extensions, they remain as additional metadata and do not actually replace the baseline ISO 9660 file names.

For each file with a long filename, mkisofs needs to store *three* names: the Rock Ridge filename (255 bytes), the Joliet filename (truncated to 63 Unicode runes), **and** the ISO 9660 filename (truncated to 8.3 bytes). When the latter truncations collide for multiple files, mkisofs will issue a warning regardless of having RR/Joliet enabled.

---

> EDIT0 : How come the path .\Master-20230929/packages/driver_v8/537.13_grid_win10_win11_server2019_server2022_dch_64bit_international.exe which contains less than 255 characters (max Rock Ridge length) is truncated to .\Master-20230929/packages/driver_v8/537.13_grid_win10_win11_server2019_server2022_dch_64bit_int.exe

It is not. The output of mkisofs is misleading because shows *two* entries at once. This particular message isn't just about truncation (all the other filenames are truncated to 8.3 quietly); it's actually about conflict handling when two long names would be truncated to the same name. In this case, the '537_…*international' got truncated to a numbered '537_1xxx.EXE' because it lost the fight against '537*…_int' which presumably kept its '537_13_G.EXE'.

(Note how the other messages mention two very different names, e.g. "disable_IPv6.cmd.txt" vs "disable_Autorun_All_users.ps1.txt". In this example, both would be truncated to "DISABLE_.TXT", so one of them won and the other had to go with "DISAB000.TXT".)

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Can you please take a look at my question in EDIT0 ?